# Parse String to Token, Export and Dynamically Echo Values

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, shellexecute

Environment : KornShell (ksh)

I am exporting variables using:

```
eval $(echo '"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD"' |  
sed 's/^"/export /g;s/=/="/g;s/#/"\nexport /g')
```

And trying to display values of these variables dynamically:

```
eval $(echo EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD|sed 's/^/echo $/g;s/=/="/g;s/#/"\necho $/g' | sed  's/=.*$//g')
```

But I am getting output as :

```
20110203-210000 echo Forigen Exchange Today echo EOD
```

I am not able to figure out why extra echo(s) is(are) displayed in it this not a satisfactory Output. It should be like below:

```
20110203-210000 
Forigen Exchange Today 
EOD
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are performing substitutions discards newlines. So the output of what's inside your parentheses looks like this:

```
echo $EffTimeStamp
echo $InputCtxNm
echo $RunType
```

But when you pass this to eval as `eval $(...)`, you effectively get:

```
echo $EffTimeStamp echo $InputCtxNm echo $RunType
```

...which hopefully makes it obvious where the extra `echo`'s are coming from.  If you just add a semicolon to end of each line to mark an explicit end-of-command, it should do what you want:

```
eval $(echo EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD|sed 's/^/echo $/g;s/=/="/g;s/#/"\necho $/g' | sed  's/=.*$/;/g')
```

The output of which is:

```
20110203-210000
Forigen Exchange Today
EOD
```